# ioctl vs netlink vs memmap to communicate between kernel space and user space

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Got some statistics information of our custom hardware to be displayed whenever user asks for using a command in the Linux user space. This implementation is currently uses PROC interface. We started adding more statistics information then we encountered a problem wherein the particular statistics command had to be executed twice for getting the entire data as PROC interface was restricted to 1 page.

As mentioned above the data transfer between the kernel and the user space is not critical but as per the data some decisions might be taken by the user. Our requirement for this interface design is that it should be capable of transferring amount of data maybe greater that 8192 bytes and the command needs to use minimal kernel resources (like locks etc.,)  and it needs to be quick.

Using ioctl can solve the issue but since the command is exactly not controlling the device but to collect some statistics information, not sure whether it is a good mechanism to use as per Linux. We are currently using 3.4 kernel; not sure whether Netlink is lossy  in this version (Previous versions I came across issues like when the queue becomes full, socket starts to drop data). mmap is another option . Can anyone suggest me what would be the best interface to use

Comment: In my project, I use mmap for a file in debugfs to transfer data from the kernel space to the user space. Here is the code: [kernel-space part](http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/source/browse/sources/utils/simple_trace_recorder/kernel/module.c), [user-space part](http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/source/browse/sources/utils/simple_trace_recorder/user/recorder.c). The amount of data transferred varies from several kilobytes to megabytes. If the buffer used there is large enough, nothing will be lost, otherwise losses are possible. May be it is not the best way but it works for me.

Comment: (continued) The implementation I used is based on what [Perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) does to output its data. My variant is simpler but probably inferior in performance to some extent (a single buffer VS per-CPU buffers in Perf, etc.) Still, it has not been a problem so far. It is up to you to decide if this technique suits your project or not, cannot really say myself.

Comment: FWIW, procfs can support sending more than 1 page of data at a time, I believe by incrementing the 'index' parameter and not setting eof until finished.

Comment: Correct; but if the data goes more than 4096 bytes then we are observing that the user space command which calls proc read has to be called once more to get the remaining data.

Comment: You can use a  "seq file" to handle a buffer larger than one page in /proc: http://kernelnewbies.org/Documents/SeqFileHowTo

Answer (score 4):

- Kernel services can send information directly to user applications over Netlink, while you’d have explicitly poll the kernel with ioctl functions, a relatively expensive operation.
- Netlink comms is very much asynchronous, with each side receiving messages at some point after the other side sends them. ioctls are purely synchronous: “Hey kernel, WAKE UP! I need you to process my request NOW! CHOP CHOP!”
- Netlink supports multicast communications between the kernel and multiple user-space processes, while ioctls are strictly one-to-one.
- Netlink messages can be lost for various reasons (e.g. out of memory), while ioctls are generally more reliable due to their immediate-processing nature.

So If you asking for statistics to kernel from user space(application) it is more reliable and easy to use IOCTL while if you generate statistics in kernel space and you want your kernel space to send those data to user space(application) you have to use Netlink sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a ioctl IO call (rather than IOR, IOW, or IORW). Ioctl's can be very useful for collecting information. You'll have a lot of flexibility this way in that you can pass different size buffers or structs to fill with data.