# How to get the address of an array in kernel module so I'll be able to use it within a user-space application?

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a kernel module named `mymodule` and in it I have :

```
static struct file_operations my_mod_fops = {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE
        .write = my_write,
        .open = my_open,
        .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl,
        .read = my_read,

};
```

all the function mapped in the previous struct were tested and they are OK. 
I want to declare globally (and staticly if available) a char `kernel_array[128]` and I want to write a userspace application that can do this:

```
int main(){

char* ptr_to_kernel_arr = get_kernel_array_address();

for (int i=0 ; i<128;++i)
    *(ptr_to_kernel_arr+i) = i;

return 0;
}
```

my difficulties are:

1. how do I get the address of `kernel_array[128]` such that I can assign values from a user space application?
2. how does the kernel knows to which module from its `lsmod` list holds the `kernel_array`
3. how [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) relates all this scenario?

I read [chapter 15](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/) and much more material but couldn't figure out how to do it.
all the examples I found [online](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#s8) declare a file and share it with the kernel and user space.

Comment: AFAIK you are trying to access kernel resource ring0 from ring3, this is only possible using system calls and not directly.

Comment: You can not map kernel memory into user-space. That would be a **huge** security hole!

Comment: I aware of the security issues my only aim is to understand the memory structure....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the `mmap` function and point to it from `file_operations`.

This will allow the user space to open your device, call `mmap` with the file descriptor, and get the address.

Note that mmap works at page resolution. So you can't map 128 bytes, but only multiples of 4K. You could map the 4K page(s) which contain the static buffer, but then the user process will be able to corrupt memory it shouldn't touch, which is highly discouraged.

Comment: call mmap with the file descriptor, and get the address. **what file descriptor do you mean?** how can I "share" only 128 bytes??? thanks

Comment: @rjayavrp, I don't have code samples. There are web pages about implementing `mmap`.

Comment: @0x90, When you open the device file associated with your driver, you get a file descriptor. This one. And there's no way to share 128 bytes  - it works on a page resolution. You have to put the 128 bytes in a dedicated page, where the rest will be unused.

Comment: @ugoren.. I used remap_pfn_range() for converting Board's physical address. then mmap() it in user space. Any idea about virtual address???

Comment: @rjayavrp, see the links to an example here (in the comments): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501527.