# How to use the DebugFS blob wrapper in a kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to find the **fastest** way of moving **large** data from kernel to user space.
Right now I'm trying out GKH's debugfs, but I'm struggling to get the blob wrapper working.

This is what I got so far:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/debugfs.h>

MODULE_AUTHOR("CREED0R");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


struct dentry *dfs;
struct debugfs_blob_wrapper *myblob;

int my_init(void)
{
    int stats[10];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        stats[i] = i;

    myblob->data = (void *) stats;
    myblob->size = (unsigned long) 10;

    dfs = debugfs_create_blob("test", 0644, NULL, myblob);

    if (dfs == NULL) {
        printk("Could not create debugfs blob\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printk("DebugFS file created\n");

    return 0;
}


void my_exit(void)
{
    printk("DebugFS file deleted\n\n");
    debugfs_remove(dfs);
}


module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

It builds, but if I run insmod my qemu instance dies horribly.

Not sure why that is. What am I missing?

Comment: As for the ways to transfer data from kernel space to the user space, have you tried mmapped buffers or netlink? They are often used for this purpose, although they may be somewhat more tricky to use.

Comment: How exactly does it die? Could you post here the kernel oops report you get (if it is an oops)? As for the code, I cannot see where exactly the structure 'myblob' points to is allocated. Perhaps, it is dereferencing of this pointer that causes the crash in `my_init()`. And BTW, returning a positive value from `my_init()` on error is probably not a good idea. IIRC, the system will consider that `my_init()` succeeded in this case. A common practice is to return a negative error code, e.g., `-EINVAL`, `-ENOMEM`, etc.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501527/) and the comments there, may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I just forgot to get mem for the blob-struct, so setting the data and size pointer inevitably killed it.

Here's the correct version, pumping 32K' worth of u32's from kernel to userspace. It builds with a 2.6.32.38 Kernel:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/debugfs.h>

#define SIZE 8192

MODULE_AUTHOR("CREED0R");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

struct dentry *dfs;
struct debugfs_blob_wrapper *myblob;

u32 *stats; /* our blob of data */

int my_init(void)
{
    int i;
    int stats_size;   /* size of our data */
    int struct_size;  /* size of the blob struct */

    struct_size = sizeof(struct debugfs_blob_wrapper);
    stats_size  = SIZE * sizeof(u32);


    /* get mem for data */
    stats = kmalloc(stats_size, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (stats == NULL) {
        printk("Could not allocate mem for data\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }


    /* fill datablob with dummy data */
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        stats[i] = i;


    /* get mem for blob struct and init */
    myblob = (struct debugfs_blob_wrapper *) kmalloc(struct_size, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (myblob == NULL) {
        printk("Could not allocate mem for blob\n");
        kfree(stats);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }


    /* only set data pointer and data size */
    myblob->data = (void *) stats;
    myblob->size = (unsigned long) stats_size;


    /* create pseudo file under /sys/kernel/debug/ with name 'test' */
    dfs = debugfs_create_blob("test", 0644, NULL, myblob);

    if (dfs == NULL) {
        printk("Could not create debugfs blob\n");
        kfree(stats);
        kfree(myblob);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    printk("DebugFS file created\n");

    return 0;
}


void my_exit(void)
{
    printk("DebugFS file deleted\n\n");

    kfree(myblob);
    kfree(stats);

    debugfs_remove(dfs);
}


module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

Comment: What error value would be appropriate for the last case where a file could not be created?

Comment: debugfs_create_*() functions may fail for several reasons. Unfortunately, they do not return the error code, so there is no easy way to determine why they have failed and no "absolutely correct" error code for your init function to return either. I suppose, it is OK to output a message about the error and return something like `-EINVAL` or `-EPERM` like you do now.

Comment: One more note: it is better to free the memory you allocate before your init function exits with an error code, in both places in this case. The kernel cannot deallocate it itself, so the memory will remain allocated and unavailable for other kernel-space components until the system is rebooted.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna remember that ; )