# Sharing (or sending) data from LKM to userland

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have some data that I need to either **share with** or **send to** from a Linux Kernel Module to userland. It doesn't really matter which one of those, as far as userland can access that data and the used method is **fast** (I'll be sending from 5.000 to 25.000 raw block of memory, of ~500 bytes each block).

The LKM doesn't need to access that data once userland has it (but nothing wrong if it's able to access it), nor userland needs to **write** to that data; it will read only.

What is the best way for doing this? Netlink? Shared memory? (is shared mem possible in any way between kernel and userland?) Something else?

Bonus: If possible, I'd be glad if userland can get events instead of having to poll (run a `while(1)` loop reading for data).

PS: Yes, I know the phrase `the best way` is hated here, so you're free to replace it with "the most suitable way", "the preferred way" or "the recommended way".

Comment: *netlink* or a pseudo file system. Perhaps even FUSE

Comment: I'd suggest a simple char driver instead. Add mmap and/or aio to reduce context switches. You can "share" memory between kernel driver and userspace using mmap. See http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ chapters 3, 6, and 15 for examples.

Comment: You can export sys or proc interface from your module and read it from userland. Use `select` system call to know whether any data is available.

Comment: you can try some asynchronous methods, like fcntl.
More info on http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch06.pdf

Comment: See that link for possible ways to do that http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html

Comment: See also this question and the comments there: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11501527/689077