# Large shared memory between Kernel space and user space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, shared-memory

I am working on a research project , and I have to share a large data structure between a kernel module and a user space program. The data structure can get very large, and since the application is performance critical, I tried using shared memory to reduce the overhead of serializing the structure(using other interfaces like NetLink). I currently made a test code based on the this link:

[http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#s8][1]

They are using *debugfs*.
I added the code in the link into my kernel module, and I wrote a custom user space program similar to theirs. I tried it with small sizes of my datastructure which worked perfectly. You can notice in the code, they are sharing only 1 page of memory. I wanted to know if there is an easy way to share much more memory than just one page.

Comment: See also the discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501527/. I use the following code for a similar purpose: [kernel-space part](http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/source/browse/sources/utils/simple_trace_recorder/kernel/module.c), [user-space part](http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/source/browse/sources/utils/simple_trace_recorder/user/recorder.c). You can ignore the compression-related stuff there and take a look at `buffer_*()` functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not really much different in doing many pages.

Allocate more pages in the open (alloc_pages or a variant), store them in an array, then your fault handler will need to (based on the faulting address):

- calculate the offset into the area with something like 
  "(((unsigned
  long) vmf->virtual_address - vma->vm_start) + (vma->vm_pgoff <<
  PAGE_SHIFT))"
- divide by PAGE_SIZE to calculate page index within the array
- range check to make sure it's valid
- pull `struct page *` from array
- call get_page to do the mapping

You can continue to use debugfs or, with a small amount of additional work in the module initialization, put a more standard character device frontend on it. (For that, nothing really needs to change outside of the module_init/module_exit parts.)

Comment: Can I do the same thing, but in the kernel I use kmalloc instead of alloc_pages, and then get pointers at page boundaries manually. My only concern is how do I access all the allocated pages as one big contiguous memory

Comment: Also I have another question, the alloc_pages function returns just one struct page* , how do I get pointers to individual pages ?

Comment: hmm... lots of options, but takes a while of looking at the code to figure out. Probably you want vmalloc_user to initially allocate. Then maybe remap_vmalloc_range in your mmap support. Haven't done it exactly this way before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @GilHamilton . I figured out that you can use pointer arithmetic from the pointer to the page returned by alloc_pages , to get the pointers to individual pages. I combined it with your idea above and worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.